# Setup document such that one page contain 2400 keystrokes?

Tags: document-configuration

How do I format a page in LaTeX such that it  will only contain 2400 keystrokes?

Anyone who knows how the preamble should look like?

Comment: Do you need to do typesetting or to measure keystrokes? This is two very different things. And you can use different tools. TeX is designed for typesetting.

Comment: I guess you mean characters, not keystrokes.

Comment: there is no easy way (assuming you mean typeset characters rather than actual keyboard strokes) but why would you want such a thing?

Comment: keystrockes spaces are included.. and  typesetting.. i was more thinking of how the permeable should look like.

Comment: The document i am writing is an exam text, which declares a page as 2400 keystrokes pr. page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You've obviously never written a grant proposal or similar (I had a similar restriction on some text for the Leverhulme Trust, but they only accept ASCII input on a website so it was easy enough).

Comment: See the stdpage package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Job applications often require this, too. But, again, they usually only take ASCII input.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is only able to max words for each line and max lines on each page.

Comment: what if the 2400th keystroke happens to be in the middle of a word?  (i'd tend to interpret the intent of this regulation as "maximum of 2400".)  with a fixed-pitch (ascii monospace) font, this approximation can easily be calculated as a function of number of words x number of lines.

Comment: I don't know the exact regulations at that point.. But it is said that a page is described as 2400 keystrokes.

Comment: But i would say that the at the 2400th keystroke if its in the middle of a word a - will be added, and continued at the next page.. Or something nicer..

Comment: I thought that something changing the width or something similar would make it happen?

Comment: @JosephWright counting characters in plain ascii text is meaningful but counting characters in typeset output, isn't really. How many characters is an fi ligature, or a stretched math delimiter or ...